# SSRS 2008 Deployment

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Whenever I wish to debug a single report (.rdl file, Report Definition file), it always deploys everything in the solution. Can someone recommend a deployment strategy in order that I can localize deployment to the specific report I am working on, and not clobber the other reports in the solution? Those may have been worked on by another employee, and why should deployment occur across the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right clicking on the specific report to deploy and choosing "Deploy" from "Solution Explorer" always works for me. Also, I keep OverwriteDatasources to false unless I specifically need to update that.